# Classic ASP URL Rewriting In IIS 10

Tags: url-rewriting, asp-classic

I want RewriteURL Classic ASP in IIS 10

ex) domain.com/login.asp -> domain.com/login/

There is also a way to use RewriteRule.

I'm not sure about this.

Please help me ..

This is my web.config file setting ..

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapting your original web.config - try this.  If you have RDP access to your server you can also use the URL Rewrite tool in IIS manager - this will write to web.config for you

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
        <defaultDocument enabled="true">
            <files>
                <add value="default.asp" />
                <add value="index.asp" />
                <add value="login.asp" />
           </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <rewrite>
           <rules>
              <rule name="Login" stopProcessing="true">
                 <match url="^login$"/>
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="login.asp"/>
                </rule>   
           </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

I tried applying this code.

but, the following error has occurred:

HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden

What should I do? T.T.

Comment: That's the Directory Browsing Prohibited message I believe.  Looking at my code again it will rewrite "domain.com/login" as "domain.com/login.asp".  If you want to include the "/" at the end then you need to change the relevant line to `<match url="^login/$"/>`.  Also, do you have a subfolder in your site called "login".  If you do that might cause a conflict.  If this is the case it might make sense to move the login.asp file to the login folder.  You can specify multiple default documents, I've amended my answer to demonstrate this

Comment: Thank you. All my questions have been resolved.